# Drag links into div

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm looking a way to make a droppable box, I mean:
Just div where user can drop a link from current page and show the link inside.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery UI has draggable and droppable functions for objects. This will meet your needs.

I'll not provide an example as the jQuery documentation does the job.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/